# How to increase nginx timeout until it loads the content fully?

Tags: nginx, dropwizard

I'm working on a web service where Nginx is used as the proxy and Dropwizard is in the backend. There is a problem with the loading of the URL, it is not loading anything that is taking more than 2 mins. Initially it was 1 minute, so I changed the `proxy_read_timeout` to `3600s;`.

But however I'm increasing it, the request is not open for more than 2 mins. The nginx error log is showing the following error,

```
2016/10/17 09:43:57 [error] 6#6: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.128.10, server: localhost, request: "GET /report-system/templates/Connection/csv/Transaction?params=PageNumber:1,PageSize:2000 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8384/report-service/dev/reports/templates/Player_GlobalTransaction/render?connref=UpamMysql&format=csv&params=PageNumber:1,PageSize:2000", host: "api.website.com"
```

Most probably the error is not with dropwizard and it is only with nginx, because when I tested without Nginx, the web-service is open until it completes loading the page. And it is **closing exactly at 2 mins** now.

Here is the full content of nginx.conf.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
}
```

And everything is running on separate docker containers. So, what is the right way to have keep the connection open until in loads the content completely? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are any of the nginx requests successfully loading? According to the docs, code 111 means that nginx can't talk to your dropwizard service at all.

Comment: @LeeAvital Yes, any requests which took less than 2 minutes are loading fine